# Почему шумовка так называется?

Tags: этимология

Всех с наступающим!
Слышал, что есть такая посуда - шумовка (правда, не очень-то представляю, что это такое)). А почему, собственно, она так называется?
Заранее спасибо, будет очень интересно узнать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ложка с дырочками для снятия пены.

Искажённое немецкое Schaumloffel.
В Словаре иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка.- Чудинов А.Н., 1910:

шумовка - польск. szumowka < szumować -снимать пену < szum -пена < ср.-в.-нем. schûm - пена).

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/30621/%D0%A8%D0%A3%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%90